# How to maintain the ratio of space occupied by components on screen

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

How can I maintain the ratio of the space occupied by the components on the screen when the screen resizes.

I have the code that looks something like as written below,
where the size of the webview1 is reduced while size if webview2 is increased on screen readjustment.
I want that both the webviews occupy equal amount of space on the screen post screen readjustment.

```
 Content = new StackLayout
        {
            Spacing = 0,
            Padding = 0,

            Children = {


                    wewbview1,
                    new StackLayout
                    {
                        BackgroundColor=Color.FromHex("#000033"),
                        Padding=2,
                        Children=
                        {
                            webview2
                        },
                        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
                    },

                    txt_Search

                }
        };
```

Comment: Add webview1 in stacklayout and add FillAndExpand.

Comment: I have already done that, both webview1 & webciew2 have `VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use an `AbsoluteLayout` to embed the two `WebView`s as you can than control the height ratio as a percentage and embed that into a `StackLayout` to bundle in your "text_search" at that bottom.

In the following example, **AFTER** removing the height of the "txt_Search" (I'm using a `BoxView` as a placeholder), the top web view gets 40% of the remaining space an the second web view gets 60%. Flip that to portrait and everything resizes correctly and maintains the 40/60 split after removing the space required for the "text_search".

*Note: I did it in `Xamarin.Forms` XAML, but it is a simple conversion to code.*

```
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <AbsoluteLayout 
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
<!--Top WebView-->
            <BoxView
                Color="Silver"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 0.4"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" />
<!--Bottom WebView-->
            <BoxView
                Color="Maroon"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1, 1, 1, 0.6"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" />
        </AbsoluteLayout>
<!--Search txt_Search-->
    <BoxView
        Color="Green"
        HeightRequest="50" />
</StackLayout>
```

[image]